# Changing seconds in the date vector

Tags: matlab, date

I would like to keep the seconds uniform in my time vector using Matlab.

for example in my data the time vector is

`01-01-2007 14:18:30; 01-01-2007 14:19:30;01-01-2007 14:20:38;01-01-2007 14:21:28`

and so on..
I want it to keep it uniform to

```
01-01-2007 14:18:30; 01-01-2007 14:19:30;01-01-2007 14:20:30;01-01-2007 14:21:30.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks.
S.S

Comment: Is it a vector of strings or of numbers? (i.e. the sort of serial date number that `datenum` creates)

Comment: I have date in both the number format as well as string format

Comment: OK so then check my answer, I've provided vectorized versions for both formats. In future, I suggest you post your data in such a way as it can be copied straight into matlab creating it in the correct types etc like I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it depends on how your dates are stored

As a **string array**:

```
s = ['01-01-2007 14:18:30'; 
     '01-01-2007 14:19:30';
     '01-01-2007 14:20:38';
     '01-01-2007 14:21:28']

s(:,end-1:end)= repmat('30', size(s,1),1)
```

or if for some reason you don't want to use `repmat` (this might be faster), you can take advantage of the fact that Matlab automatically broadcasts scalars:

```
s(:,end-1)='3';
s(:,end)= '0';
```

or as a **cell array of strings**:

```
c = {'01-01-2007 14:18:30'; 
     '01-01-2007 14:19:30';
     '01-01-2007 14:20:38';
     '01-01-2007 14:21:28'}

cellfun(@(x)([x(1:end-2),'30']), c, 'uni', false)
```

or if you have your **dates as numbers** then

```
s = ['01-01-2007 14:18:30'; 
     '01-01-2007 14:19:30';
     '01-01-2007 14:20:38';
     '01-01-2007 14:21:28']
n = datenum(s, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')

%// Note that n will store numbers in units of days, so to round off to the nearest 30 seconds we must round to multiples of 1/(# of 30 seconds per day)
k = 2*60*24; %//The number of 30 seconds per day
round(n*k)/k
```

or with any of them, you can **covert to a date vector**:

```
v = datevec(s, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')
```

or

```
v = datevec(n)
```

where `s` or `n` are defined as above. Now you can simply go

```
v(:,end) = 30;
```

and then use `datestr(v)` or `datenum(v)` to go back.

Comment: @user3876557 Glad it helped, please mark it as solved by clicking on the tick icon at the top left of the answer if it does indeed answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the data strings the last the seconds are always the last two places in the string so you can just replace them by using:

```
date_string='01-01-2007 14:18:28';
uni_seconds = '30';

date_string(end-1:end)=uni_seconds
```

The last line states that the last two places (end-1 and end) are to be replaced by the variable uni_seconds which is the string containing the seconds you want to set.

Comment: But what if I have more than 100,000 datalines. It would be hard for me to identify data points whose seconds needs to be changed